# PhpSpreadsheet return file instead of saving it

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have generated xmlx file and I am able to save it and provide it for the user via:

```
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
header('Location: hello world.xlsx');
```

However, then the file remains on the hard drive. I need to get rid of it as it is a security threat.

I tried unlinking the file

```
unlink('hello world.xlsx');
```

but that deletes the file too early so the user doesn't have access to it.
If it can work with unlink then I need to be sure the file will be deleted (so proper using of `die();` and such)

**EDIT:**
It is not only for security reasons anymore. The provider doesn't allow saving files so it is the only way to go.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `php://output`

```php
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
$writer->save("php://output");
```

Comment: That doesn't work as it returns what would be on the page rather that what would be in the file. So it is returning random warning instead of the file.

Comment: @Brambor what is the warning there?

Comment: It is unrelated, it was there before when it worked, `Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given in "my_file_path"\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\DocProps.php on line 148`

Comment: It essentialy offers a file to save. That file is a xls file that has this warning in `A2` So it is what would be on the page.

Comment: @Brambor I would suggest to get rid of warnings first (i.e., to fix them) and then to try to generate file again.

Comment: But it is unrelated! I can generate the file, save it perfectly, by provided code and then header to it!

Comment: When I do not use saved file as xmlx template then the warning disapears and the file is compleatly empty. So it was unrelated, I god rid of the warning.

Comment: You were right afer all. Once all warnings were supressed the file showed just fine. The typical "you have to not echo anything if you wat to use header" error mistake.

Comment: Add `exit();` at the end so it does not download rest of the page

Comment: I am getting cors error in laravel 7.34, when using these settings. Maybe you could help me, thank you very much.

Comment: @JG_GJ Consider opening new question with detailed description of your setup, please and tag me here.

Answer (score 3):

You could send the file directly after its creation, instead of the redirect to the file.

```
$filename = 'hello world.xlsx';
$writer->save($filename);

// Set the content-type:
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename); // send file
unlink($filename); // delete file
exit;
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I found out that on the server (unlike localhost) the saving is prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an in memory file pointer and read back from it.

```php
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

$fp = fopen("php://memory", "rw");
$writer->save($fp);
rewind($fp);

$contents = "";
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $contents .= fread($fp, 8000);
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I guess depending on your web server setup (FPM/FastCGI), buffering is probably the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

### call ob_end_clean(); just before the $writer->save('php://output').

> ob_end_clean();
> $writer->save('php://output');