PHP: saving a table, then download it
I am making a feature that allows the user to telecahrge table data directly into excel. But I have a problem when saving the file. I write my file with php spreadsheet, then I try to save it, before downloading the created file.
But I can't save it. Do you know why?
My button to dl:
<td style='border:1px solid grey; border-top:0; border-bottom:0; border-left:0; border-right:0;' align='center' colspan='1'>
    <?php 
    $linkXlsx = './inc/fin/test/'.$_POST['soct'].date('Y-m-d').'.xlsx';
    ?>
    <a href='<?php echo $linkXlsx; ?>' download>
        <img src='./img/excel.png' height='30' alt='Télécharger' />
    </a>
</td>

My function:
function download () {

    $Ecritures = get_ListeEcrituresCegid ( $_POST['soct'] , $_POST['datd'] , $_POST['datf'] );

    $NomFichier = $_POST['soct'].date('Y-m-d').'.xlsx';

    $Classeur = new Spreadsheet();
    $Classeur->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial Nova');
    $Classeur->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(9);
    $Feuille = $Classeur->getActiveSheet(); 

    $Feuille->setCellValue('A1', 'EXERCICE' );
    $Feuille->setCellValue('B1', 'JOURNAL' );
    $Feuille->setCellValue('C1', 'PIECE' );
    $Feuille->setCellValue('D1', 'COMPTE CLIENT' );

    $Writer = new Xlsx($Classeur);
    $Writer->save('./inc/fin/test/'.$NomFichier);

    $cellColors = [
        'A1' => 'd4e6f1',   'B1' => 'd4e6f1',   'C1' => 'd4e6f1',
        'D1' => 'd4e6f1',
    ];

    foreach ($cellColors as $cell => $color) {
        $Feuille->getStyle($cell)->getFill()->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID);
        $Feuille->getStyle($cell)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB($color);
    }

    $rowIndex = 2;

    foreach ( $Ecritures as $e ) {  
        echo $Ecritures;
        $Feuille->setCellValue('A'.$rowIndex, $e['E_EXERCICE']);
        $Feuille->setCellValue('B'.$rowIndex, $e['E_JOURNAL']);
        $Feuille->setCellValue('C'.$rowIndex, $e['E_DEBIT']);
        $Feuille->setCellValue('D'.$rowIndex, $e['E_COMPTECLI']);       
        $rowIndex++;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $NomFichier . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $Writer = new Xlsx($Classeur);
    $Writer->save('./inc/fin/test/'.$NomFichier);

    return $Writer;
}


What do you mean with save? Do you want to offer it as download? Then you need to send file to output like readfile('./inc/fin/test/'.$NomFichier);.

In my 'download' method there is this line:
$Writer->save('./inc/fin/test/'.$FileName);
It's supposed to “save” the file in the “test” folder. The user doesn't have access to this folder, so I want him to be able to download this same file by clicking on my button

Yes, so you can deliver it via readfile() without giving him permission to that directory.

If you are using the PhpSpreadsheed library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319493/phpspreadsheet-return-file-instead-of-saving-it
